# How to download CSS file through JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

- Is it possible to download a CSS file through JQuery?
- Also, I need a callback which will notify me that the file is downloaded. The file will not be downloaded if the file exists in the client machine.

Please help with sample code. Thanks.

Comment: It seems rather strange to change on the fly a css? Could you be more explicit of what you want to do and the purpose of this?

Comment: What's the purpose of this, just out of curiosity?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.get('/css/foobar/tooltips.css', function(data) {
        var style = document.createElement('style'),
            head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElemen;

        style.type = "text/css";
        style.textContent = style.text = data;

        head.appendChild(style, head.firstChild); 
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The above code would download the contents of `tooltips.css`. When the file is transfered, a new `link` node is created and the contents from `tooltips.css` are inserted. After that, the new node is appended into your document and all css rules will apply.

If you need/want to transfer many files dynamically, I would recommend a script like [supplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply)

Answer (score 0):

Adding more selector in your css and applying the change in the DOM will be simpler.

Local file access are restricted by the browser. This will probably lead to a big complexity of your code.